# Typeahead list is not loading based on 'change' event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `typeahead` jquery plugin for autocompletion of list. Right now typeahead list will load with custom params for the first time only. Second time list will not reload.

In views,

```
$('#state_id').on('change', function(){
  $(".state-based-city").typeahead({
    ajax: {
      url: "/typeaheads/cities?id=" + $("#state_id :selected").val(),
      timeout: 500,
      displayField: "value",
      method: "get"
    }
  });
});
```

As per this code, when I change the state value then city list will load based on it. Second time if I change the state value then city list will load based on old state value.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please use async:false

Comment: Remove change event too

Comment: Still list is not getting reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this,

```
$(".state-based-city").typeahead({
  ajax: {
    url: "/typeaheads/cities",
    timeout: 500,
    displayField: "value",
    method: "get",
    preDispatch: function (query) {
    return {
      query: query,
      id: $("#state_id :selected").val()
   }
}
```